# command to run robot file where i can specify python version as well

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have installed both python 2.7 and 3.7 on my system and configured python 3.7 in pycharm.

Ran below command to installed robotframework for web automation:

```
python3 -m pip install robotframework
python3 -m pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

Written  this code in pycharm:

```
*** Settings ***


Library SeleniumLibrary


*** Variables ***

${Browser}  Chrome

${url}  http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/register.php


*** Test Cases ***

Test title

    Open_Browser  ${url}  ${Browser}
```

now when I trying to run this code from cmd with command "robot TC_002.robot"

getting error:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\python\RobotFramework\TC_002.robot' on line 2: Non-existing setting 'Library SeleniumLibrary
```

Is there another command which I can use to run from cmd along with python version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you didn't include at least 2 spaces between `Library` and `SeleniumLibrary`, you did this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library SeleniumLibrary
```

when I run this using robot, it gives me exactly the same error:

```
Non-existing setting 'Library SeleniumLibrary'.
```

You should write:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
```

Please format your code next time, it's hard to find out where the error is when the code is just placed in between normal text.